# Fetch details from database using onclick()

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have simple HTML form on which user will enter token number. How can I fetch details from database using `onclick()` event when user enter token number and click on `fetch details`.
After fetching the details user will click on `Pay with PayPal` button to complete payment.

HTML Form:

```html
<form class="responsive" action="payments.php" method="post" id="paypal1">
            <strong><big>Have Token? Checkout here...</big></strong><br><br>
            <p>Token Number: 
                <input type="text" name="token" placeholder="Enter Token Number" autocomplete="off" maxlength="45" required />
                <input type="button" id="token-btn" value="Fetch Details" onClick="fetch-details()">
            </p>    
            <button class="btn btn-success">Pay With PayPal</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download jquery from jquery site include the script in the page needed, then create a php file lemme call mine fetch.php that fetches the details you want, something like this

```
<?php
require_once 'your_connection';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
 $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['id'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='$id'";
  if($query_run= mysqli_query($query)){
   if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
     echo"<h1>$row['details']</h1>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

then below the included script of downloaded do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#fetchDetails").click(function(){
      $.post("fetch.php",{id:the_id_of_the_details_you_want_to_fetch},function(data) 
      {
        $("#id_of_where_you_want_to_place_details_on_page").html(data);
      })
   });
})
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is either:

1. Old-style, page-refresh: Have the button submit a form, have your PHP code do the DB work, and show a new page.
2. Use ajax:

   - Have a JavaScript event handler that makes an ajax call to your PHP code (using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) [on modern browsers] or [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest))
   - Have your PHP code do the DB work and return the details, perhaps using [`json_encode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to send the details back as JSON
   - Have your JavaScript ajax success handler use the details to update the page via [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)